# User Input in Struts2

Tags: java, struts2, user-input

I developed a back-end for my s/w in java and the interface using Struts2 .I am calling servlet class from the last action class and running my business logic from there which is split across multiple classes.Now in the middle of the code,I need to take user input if a particular method gets called..And again one of the input is optional(only if a particular keyword is present in the line I am scanning) and the other is mandatory if that function is called and after taking the input the code should continue from that left place.The code need not accept any input and should continue if the function is not called.Can someone help me with the flow and basics of how I can do this.Thanks!

Comment: You are thinking of it wrong. With a web application using the Struts paradigm, you display a page to the user then they type stuff and click submit. Then it comes back to you and you can respond with something to show on the screen. Or maybe they click a link and you display another page. Its not linear. Its that they do something and you respond. You may respond with a page they have to fill in but preserving the state across such situations is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

An Action calling a Servlet ? The Action IS your "Servlet". You won't probably need Servlet anymore, except for rare cases.

To make it simple, the Action prepares the data for the view, then invokes the view (JSP, ore something else):

> LoadDataToShowAction.java ========> dataToShow.jsp

in dataToShow.jsp, the user enters data, then clicks a button, invoking another Action:

> dataToShow.jsp ========> ProcessUserDataAction.java

And so on.

Note that in the middle of the `========>` part, there is the Interceptor Stack.